# Synchronously Call PowerShell script from VBScript

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a PowerShell script that I need to run from a VBScript and I need the VBScript to wait on the PowerShell to finish (but the two don't need to communicate at all). Here's code that will execute the powershell, but the VBScript doesn't wait:

```vb
Set objShell = (CreateObject("Wscript.shell"))

objShell.Run ("powershell -noexit -file e:\powershell\vb_to_powershell_test.ps1")

MsgBox("Powershell execution complete")
```

This script will pop up with "Powershell execution complete" instantly, while the PowerShell is still running.

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968356/how-to-programmatically-wait-for-shell-command-to-finish-running) there is a `True` flag I could add that forces VB to wait. Like so, maybe:

```vb
objShell.Run ("powershell -noexit -file e:\powershell\vb_to_powershell_test.ps1", True)
```

That isn't working for me, as the script always complains about "cannot use parenthesis when calling a sub", which is [a whole thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/).

I suspect this is a VisualBasic vs. VB.NET issue, but I'm stuck with VisualBasic here.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This other post [may be what you are looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279404/vbscript-how-to-make-program-wait-until-process-has-finished)

Answer (score 3):

Synchronous/asynchronous execution is controlled by the 3rd parameter of the [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method (2nd parameter controls the window style). Set that parameter to `True` to run the command synchronously:

```vb
objShell.Run "powershell -noexit -file e:\some.ps1", 1, True
```

The second parameter can be omitted, but you still need to maintain the position:

```vb
objShell.Run "powershell -noexit -file e:\some.ps1", , True
```

Parentheses can only be used if you call the method with a [`Call`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcx04ck5%28v=vs.84%29) statement:

```vb
Call objShell.Run("powershell -noexit -file e:\some.ps1", 1, True)
```

or in situations where you use the return value, e.g. when assigning it to a variable:

```vb
retval = objShell.Run("powershell -noexit -file e:\some.ps1", 1, True)
```

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) for further explanation.